# Error with php5-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I just installed nginx along with php-fpm when I encountered a 403 error when trying to view one of my sites. When I checked the nginx error logs, I saw a few things like permission denied, but I also noticed this:

```
/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: no such file or directory)
```

But I installed php-fpm, why would it be looking to load php5-fpm? I'm stumped, any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: server block in default.conf

```
server {
listen   81 default_server;
server_name  _;

#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

# Load configuration files for the default server block.
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
```

}

Comment: nginx server block config ? I don't know if there is a package called php-fpm, at least not in Ubuntu 14.04 and Debian 8. There is php5-fpm. What distro are you using?

Comment: Have you started php-fpm service?

Comment: Yes, the service is started. I could install php5-fpm but I just don't understand why it would be looking for php5 rather than php which is what I installed.

Comment: Can you post your server block config?

Comment: Just added it to my first post. You mean in the default.conf file?

Comment: You need to create a server block for every website that you host. Start with this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-centos-7

Comment: Yes I did that from that tutorial but it's still giving me errors in the log. I'm going to check with my host and see. I'll post back here if I can get it working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

By default, most distributions configure php-fpm to listen to TCP socket on port 9000.

Make sure your fpm is actually configured to listen to a file socket

`listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

Or configure nginx to `fcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000`

Here's a full guide

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-nginx-and-php-fpm-setup-for-php-fpm/

Comment: Which file would that be in?

Comment: Look for a php[5]-fpm.conf in /etc, exact location depends on your distro

Comment: Don't forget to setup the right User and Group in that pool to avoid `permission denied`